# adb: failed to open flutter project path/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk:Operation not permitted

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the full error message.

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to open /[FLUTTER PROJECT PATH]/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Operation not permitted
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

When I build and run my `Flutter` project on `Android emulator` or `physical device`, I always end up seeing this message.

It'd worked well so far, but after adopted and threw out some new packages, it came to my debug console and it really made me get mad.

It works well when I open its `android` directory and build with Android Studio, or when I build it on iOS devices(in both cases of physical and simulator). But it only happens when I build it on Android in debug mode.

Below is what I've tried so far:

```
flutter clean - flutter pub get cmds

remove android directory and flutter create . cmd

remove build directory and flutter build cmd

adb root

adb unroot

adb kill server - adb start server

adb reboot
```

I was just wondering if the problem was related to adb, flutter, or android.

Thanks for reading my issue.